# Android - Stop (Intercept) C2DM Push Notification if app is running?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I have implemented C2DM (Android Push Notification) to my app and all is working fine. However, when my app is running, I am able to get notifications. May I know how if I am able to stop the push notification from coming in if my application is running? I only want to receive push notifications only when my app is not running. Because as far as I know, the APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) would check if the app is running or not before sending the push notification. Does C2DM do this too?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Moujib is right. I am facing the same problem as you, I'd like to stop the push notifications if the app is running. I did managed to solve the problem by using the code from here: http://kpbird.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-check-application-is-running.html

Use that piece of code to check if your app is running or not. Then, if the app is running, I did nothing to it, if it is not running, I would then send/get the push notifications. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Well you can disable your notifications when the app is running , in other words , push messages will still get to you but you have the control to make a notification or not .

If app is running or in foreground
 no notifications 
else
 Notify ...

Comment: Thanks for your response, @moujib. But how can I check if the app is running/in foreground?

Comment: Easy here we are : stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background/5862048#5862048

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to check if the app is running in the c2dm receiver class?

Comment: Yes I think it's doable , give it a try and see if you can pop a log when you receive a push notification while your app is in foreground on your onMessage callback

Comment: Hi, I still have no idea how I can stop the notification from popping in if I am still in the app. Can you please guide me? I am quite lost.